# How to send Json object through java sockets?

Tags: java, json, sockets, objectoutputstream

How do you send Json object's through sockets preferable through ObjectOutputStream class in java this is what I got so far

```
    s = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 7777);
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("type", "CONNECT");
    out.writeObject(object);
```

But this gives an java.io.streamcorruptedexception exception  any suggestions?

Comment: Don't you think it would be relevant **which** exception you get?

Comment: @FelixKling sorry forget that updated the question

Comment: Why use JSON if you use native Java serialization. Why not send a Java object directly? And which JSONOnject class are you talking about?

Comment: This code does not throw that exception. You can only get `StreamCorruptedException` from the *reading* code, which you haven't shown.

Answer (score 19):

Instead of using `ObjectOutputStream`, you should create an `OutputStreamWriter`, then use that to write the *JSON text* to the stream. You need to choose an encoding - I would suggest UTF-8. So for example:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("type", "CONNECT");
Socket s = new Socket("192.168.0.100", 7777);
try (OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
        s.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    out.write(json.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `StandardCharsets`; I'd not run across the constants (which, IMHO, are in a stupid location).

Comment: UTF8 is the *only* byte encoding for JSON.  Any other encoding and it's not legally JSON.

Comment: @HotLicks: Interesting - where's that defined, just for my future reference?

Comment: In the standard: "JSON text is a sequence of Unicode code points".

Comment: @HotLicks: that doesn't mean that these unicode code points must be encoded as UTF8. UTF8 is one of many ways to transform unicode code points to bytes. You could also use UTF16 or UTF32 for example. Isn't the encoding a property of the transport protocol (HTTP, most of the time)?

Comment: I said "byte encoding".  And the point is you'd never use ASCII or 8859_1 some non-UTF DBCS encoding.

Comment: @HotLicks: But you could easily use UTF-16, or UTF-32... or you *could* use ISO-8859-1 if for some reason you knew that the JSON would never contain any data which isn't representable in that encoding. It does sound like claiming UTF-8 as the only valid encoding is simply incorrect. If JSON is a sequence of Unicode code points, how those are encoded as binary is a transport implementation detail.

Comment: But many parsers accept a byte stream (in fact, this is probably preferred), and if any multi-byte characters are encoded and the encoding is not UTF8 then you have problems.

Comment: See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt: *JSON text SHALL be encoded in Unicode.  The default encoding is
   UTF-8.

   Since the first two characters of a JSON text will always be ASCII
   characters [RFC0020], it is possible to determine whether an octet
   stream is UTF-8, UTF-16 (BE or LE), or UTF-32 (BE or LE) by looking
   at the pattern of nulls in the first four octets.*

Comment: @HotLicks: If a parser accepts a byte stream, I'd expect it to also accept an encoding. It may *default* to UTF-8, but requiring that seems over the top. But this seems a very long way from your original position of claiming it's the *only* legal encoding for JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet: Excellent - thanks for the definitive reference. So there are multiple legal encodings compliant with RFC 4627, but UTF-8 is assumed by default. Makes sense - slightly stricter than XML, but still entirely reasonable.

Comment: Apple doesn't agree with you.  The NSJSONSerialization kit for iPhone generates only UTF8 and accepts only UTF8/16/32 (with 8 strongly preferred).

Comment: @HotLicks: Well, that just means Apple doesn't implement RFC 4627. That's not the same as claiming that JSON encoded using UTF-16 "isn't legal". Frankly UTF-8 would almost certainly be the best encoding to use in general, so I don't think we're arguing in terms of practicalities - but I wouldn't make a blanket statement like your original one.

Comment: How is Apple's kit not compliant?  And I never said UTF-16 wasn't legal JSON.  I said "byte encoding".  UTF-16 is not "byte encoding".

Comment: @HotLicks: Um, yes it is. What *exactly* do you understand by the term "byte encoding"? While I wouldn't use exactly that term, I'd understand it to be a conversion between Unicode code points and bytes. By that definition, UTF-16 is most *definitely* a byte encoding. (See System.Text.Encoding for example in .NET.) If you're using the term to mean something different, please give a precise definition.

Comment: @HotLicks: (To be more precise, there are two varieties of UTF-16 depending on endianness of the bytes. See http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html for more about UTF-* encodings.)

Comment: Could you please explain why to use an OutputStreamWriter in stead of ObjectOutputStream? I know it's been a year, but I just came across this and was wondering why.

Comment: @Daniel: Why would you want to wrap a nice portable format (JSON) in a Java-specific binary serialization format?

Comment: Jumping into this blast from the past, my read of the `OutputStreamWriter` documentation (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/OutputStreamWriter.html) is that the `OutputStreamWriter` should be wrapped in a `BufferedWriter` "so as to avoid frequent converter invocations". The example given is `new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out))`. Is this still true and consistent with your collective experience?

Comment: @TomStambaugh: The documentation says to *consider* doing that, not that one *should* do that. In this case, there's only a single call to `write`, so the motivation of avoiding "frequent converter invocations" is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Indeed, absolutely. I appreciate your immediate and constructive response. I was looking at this in the context of a longer-lived service. I found a simpler and more direct alternative.

Answer (score -2):

An [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#:%7E:text=An%20ObjectOutputStream%20writes%20primitive%20data,a%20file%20for%20the%20stream.) writes primitive data types and graphs of Java objects to an OutputStream. The objects can be read (reconstituted) using an ObjectInputStream. Persistent storage of objects can be accomplished by using a file for the stream. If the stream is a network socket stream, the objects can be reconstituted on another host or in another process.

A data output stream lets an application write primitive Java data types to an output stream in a portable way. An application can then use a data input stream to read the data back in." You don't need to write primitive data types in binary, so do not use [DataOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html)

An OutputStreamWriter is a bridge from character streams to byte streams: Characters written to it are encoded into bytes using a specified charset. The charset that it uses may be specified by name or may be given explicitly, or the platform's default charset may be accepted.

You need to create an OutputStreamWriter for sending json objects to the client

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("name", "harris");
obj.put("age", 23);
out.write(obj.toString());
```

You can read the output data from the client using InputStreamReader by this way

```
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
int data = input.read();
while (data != -1) {
    System.out.print((char)data);
    data = input.read();
}
```